# In form validate's submithandler ajax getting Uncaught TypeError: form.serialize is not a function

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Getting this error in console Uncaught TypeError: form.serialize is not a function . How Can I fix this error in form validate submithandler's ajax ?

```
$('#form').validate({
                errorClass:  'fieldError',
                onkeyup:     false,
                onblur:      false,
                errorElement:'label',

                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: form.action,
                        type: form.method,
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        success: function(response) {
                            if (response == false)
                            {alert('could not submit!')}
                        }

                    });

                }
            });
```

Comment: use $('#form').serialize()

Comment: FYI - there is no such option called `onblur`.  The closest option is called `onfocusout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for the jQuery validate plugin, the `submitHandler` callback gets the native form as the only argument.

The native form has no `serialize()` method, as it's a jQuery method.
You have to wrap the native form in `$()`

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

    var $form = $(form);

    $.ajax({
        url     : $form.attr('action'),
        type    : $form.attr('method'),
        data    : $form.serialize(),
        success : function(response) {
            if (response == false) {
                alert('could not submit!')}
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution already but I was doing it like this var $form = $(this); so getting another exception. Fixed now +1 for this solution . Thanks Sir !

Comment: @Haroon, within the `submitHandler`, `$(this)` is the validator object, not the form.