# Javascript object obtained from on-click event passed to a function not able to be posted as form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

Appreciate any insights...

I capture form button click event for submission:

```
$('.saveItem').on( 'click', function(e) {
    submitItemSave(true, e); 
});
```

Calling a user-defined function on click and passing the event, e into :

```
function submitItemSave(first_call, currEv) {
```

which initially does some input validation (i.e. where first_call parameter is true)

And then recalls itself if no validation errors, setting “first_call” = false

```
if(first_call){
    $('#multiCribSubmitMsg').show();
    setTimeout(function() { submitItemSave(false, currEv) }, 1);
} else {
    var currForm;
```

Then, it continues at the “else” above, setting:

```
currForm = currEv.currentTarget.closest('form')
```

I dump that var as follows:

```
console.log('bottom: ', typeof(currForm));
```

which gives:

bottom:  object

And:

```
console.log('last: ', currForm)
```

Which gives **very form-like output as shown below*****.

However, when I try to post that

```
$.post('actRequestItemForm.cfm', currForm.serialize(), function() {
    $('#multiCribSubmitMsg').hide();
    loadUpExistingItems();
});
```

I get:

userRequestForm.js:415 **Uncaught TypeError: currForm.serialize is not a function**
at submitItemSave (userRequestForm.js:415:49)
at userRequestForm.js:370:31
...

*****userRequestForm.js:414** last:

```
<form class="itemForm" name="itemEditForm18221">
<input type="hidden" name="requestId" value="76041">
<input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="18221">
<div class="itemFormLabel reqd">" Crib/Box"::after</div>
<div class="itemFormInput"><input type="number" name="cribBox" id="cribBoxHint" value="5001" required="required" class="expand validateMe ui-autocomplete-input" maxlength=" 50" autocomplete="off"></div>
<div class="itemFormLabel reqd">" Item Number"::after</div>
<div class="itemFormInput"><input type="text" name="itemNumber" value="881804" required="required" class="expand validateMe ui-autocomplete-input" maxlength=" 25" autocomplete="off"></div>
<div class="itemFormLabel reqd">" Quantity"::after</div>
<div class="itemFormInput"><input type="number" name="quantity" value="7" required="required" class="expand validateMe" maxlength=" 2"></div>
<div class="itemFormLabel reqd">" Delivery Location"::after</div>
<div class="itemFormInput"><input type="text" name="ftwDeliveryLocation" value="q / r / s" required="required" class="expand validateMe ui-autocomplete-input" maxlength=" 50" autocomplete="off"></div>
<div class="itemFormValidationMessage"></div>
<input type="button" value="Save Changes" class="saveItem">" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; "
<input type="button" value="Cancel Changes" class="cancelItemChange">
<input type="button" value="Remove" class="buttonRemove" myid style="display: none;">
</form>

userRequestForm.js:415 Uncaught TypeError: currForm.serialize is not a function
    at submitItemSave (userRequestForm.js:415:49)
    at userRequestForm.js:370:31
submitItemSave @ userRequestForm.js:415
(anonymous) @ userRequestForm.js:370
setTimeout (async)
submitItemSave @ userRequestForm.js:370
(anonymous) @ userRequestForm.js:303
dispatch @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved that error by doing:

```
currForm = $(currEv.currentTarget.closest('form'));
```

Per (accepted answer):

[In form validate's submithandler ajax getting Uncaught TypeError: form.serialize is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081360/in-form-validates-submithandler-ajax-getting-uncaught-typeerror-form-serialize)

Thanks for looking!